# Retornar mensagem unica após 5 repetições de comando

Tags: vbs, vbscript

Tenho um código bem simples que checa se o usuário existe e retorna uma mensagem  "Acesso Garantido" ou "Acesso Negado".

O problema é que preciso chamar essa Sub 5 vezes, o que vai retornar 5 ***MsgBox***. Como eu conseguiria retornar uma unica ***MsgBox*** com as 5 informações dizendo tipo 'Usuário Y não existe...'?

```
Dim UserName
Dim UserPass    

Dim Mateus: Mateus = "Math"
Dim SenhaMateus: SenhaMateus ="123"

Dim Chris: Chris = "Chris99"
Dim SenhaChris: SenhaChris = "@#23"

Dim Samurai: Samurai = "Samuca"
Dim SenhaSamurai: SenhaSamurai = "CH1N4" 

Dim Kaguya: Kaguya = "Kaguy"
Dim SenhaKaguya: SenhaKaguya = "Naruto"

Dim Maroto: Maroto = "Marotinho"
Dim SenhaMaroto: SenhaMaroto = "78D99D"

Dim Jorge: Jorge = "Jorge"
Dim SenhaJorge: SenhaJorge = "Benjor"

Call ChecaUser(Mateus,SenhaMateus)
Call ChecaUser(Chris,SenhaChris)
Call ChecaUser(Samurai,SenhaSamurai)
Call ChecaUser(Kaguya,SenhaKaguya)
Call ChecaUser(Maroto,SenhaMaroto)
Call ChecaUser(Jorge,SenhaJorge)

Sub ChecaUser(UserName,UserPass)
if (UserName = "Jorge" and UserPass = "Benjor") then
MsgBox "Acesso Garantido"
Else
MsgBox  "Usuario não existe"
End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma das maneiras é criar uma variável para ir armazenando os nomes que são ou não válidos através do seu método `ChecaUser` e depois é só mostrar no `MsgBox` essa variável. Ex:

```
Dim UserName
Dim UserPass

Dim InvalidUsers
Dim ValidUsers

Dim Mateus: Mateus = "Math"
Dim SenhaMateus: SenhaMateus ="123"

Dim Chris: Chris = "Chris99"
Dim SenhaChris: SenhaChris = "@#23"

Dim Samurai: Samurai = "Samuca"
Dim SenhaSamurai: SenhaSamurai = "CH1N4" 

Dim Kaguya: Kaguya = "Kaguy"
Dim SenhaKaguya: SenhaKaguya = "Naruto"

Dim Maroto: Maroto = "Marotinho"
Dim SenhaMaroto: SenhaMaroto = "78D99D"

Dim Jorge: Jorge = "Jorge"
Dim SenhaJorge: SenhaJorge = "Benjor"

Call ChecaUser(Mateus,SenhaMateus)
Call ChecaUser(Chris,SenhaChris)
Call ChecaUser(Samurai,SenhaSamurai)
Call ChecaUser(Kaguya,SenhaKaguya)
Call ChecaUser(Maroto,SenhaMaroto)
Call ChecaUser(Jorge,SenhaJorge)

If (Len(InvalidUsers) > 0) Then
    MsgBox "Usuário(s) inexistentes(s): " & InvalidUsers
End If

if (Len(ValidUsers) > 0) Then
     MsgBox "Usuário(s) válido(s): " & ValidUsers
End If    

Sub ChecaUser(UserName,UserPass)
    If (UserName = "Jorge" and UserPass = "Benjor") then
        ValidUsers = ValidUsers & UserName & " | "
    Else
        InvalidUsers = InvalidUsers & UserName & " | "
    End If
End Sub
```

Bem vindo ao SOpt.